# Message queuing per tenant

Tags: message-queue, scheduling

I have an API where clients submits jobs asynchronously which can easily be divided into many smaller tasks. Sometimes we receive more jobs than we can process real time and therefor I want to have a job queue for each client so that I can round robin process jobs between clients. This is so that if one client submits a giant job tiny jobs from other clients wont have to wait for the giant task.

For my specific case it's important that each task is processed exactly once.

[image: A visual diagram of the description above]

I've been looking at RabbitMQ but I haven't found a way for a consumer (the processor in this case) to subscribe to all queues matching a pattern like queues can subscribe to an exchange.

Kafka seems to have the client partitioning I want but doesn't seem to offer enough certainty that tasks will be delivered once. The ability for multiple consumers to have different offsets amplifies that even more.

Is there a message queue broker which can be setup to do what I've described?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to guarantee exactly once processing in your case. What should the messaging system do when task processing is completed, but due to hardware failure the acknowledgement is not delivered? It can either drop the message (practically loosing the customer request) or redeliver it (which violates exactly once). There should be a way to check if request was already processed. It would allow you make the task processing idempotent.

BTW I think queues are not good fit for your use case. Check out [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that would give you a lot of features and visibility into processing out of the box.

Cadence offers a lot of advantages over using queues for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Distributed CRON support

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.